# How can I check which cookies were accepted in android webview if any?

Tags: android, cookies, webview

I need to accept cookies in android webview when I want to access a specific webpage. I don't know if I have to enable anything to do this. I just know that in the process when submitting a form from one page and proceed to another there have to be some cookies accepted.

I would be really grateful if someone could tell me how can I check if any cookies were accepted when attempting to load desired webpage. In which method should I do that?

All previous similar questions that I read were dealing with cookies in `onCreate()` but nothing worked for me and that doesn't make sense to me because at that point I don't come to that webpage yet because it's not the first page which I open with `loadUrl()` in onCreate but I browse to it later.

In which method and how would I accept cookies when accessing that page and how would I check if any of them were accepted?